# Oracle XML type parsing issue

Tags: oracle, extract, xmltype

My XML File is stored in oracle column

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BasicProductTemplateType xmlns="http://www.asia.com/app/Product_2_0"  xmlns:jBos_Common_1_0="http://www.asia.com/jBos/Common_1_0">
    <jBos_Common_1_0:displayName>
        <jBos_Common_1_0:key>label</jBos_Common_1_0:key>
    </jBos_Common_1_0:displayName>
    <jBos_Common_1_0:description>label</jBos_Common_1_0:description>
    <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="invoicingCoId" value="2"/>
    <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="currencyCode" value="CNY"/>
    <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="taxStatus" value="false"/>
    <productRatePlan>
        <name>Default</name>
        <selectionType>SELECTONE</selectionType>
    </productRatePlan>
    <productAttribute>
        <name>Baiying_attr_00</name>
        <displayName>
            <jBos_Common_1_0:key>Label</jBos_Common_1_0:key>
        </displayName>
        <type entityName="bmiasia.app.siulib.siu.common.StringSIU"/>
        <description>
            <jBos_Common_1_0:key>Label</jBos_Common_1_0:key>
        </description>
        <required>false</required>
        <source>INTERNAL</source>
    </productAttribute>
</BasicProductTemplateType>`

When I am trying to execute the below query i am not getting any result

SELECT XMLTYPE(XMLDATA).EXTRACT('//productAttribute/name/text()').getStringVal() FROM TABLE

What is wrong in my query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the world of XMLs most annoy 'feature' - namespaces.  As your XML document has namespaces defined in it, you need to specify the namespace of the nodes you are selecting.  Note that there are two namespaces in your XML document, so you need to use the correct one.  The following works as a PLSQL block for your XML:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
  v_xml varchar2(32767) := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <BasicProductTemplateType xmlns="http://www.asia.com/app/Product_2_0" xmlns:jBos_Common_1_0="http://www.asia.com/jBos/Common_1_0"> <jBos_Common_1_0:displayName> <jBos_Common_1_0:key>label</jBos_Common_1_0:key> </jBos_Common_1_0:displayName> <jBos_Common_1_0:description>label</jBos_Common_1_0:description> <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="invoicingCoId" value="2"/> <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="currencyCode" value="CNY"/> <jBos_Common_1_0:extensionProperty name="taxStatus" value="false"/> <productRatePlan> <name>Default</name> <selectionType>SELECTONE</selectionType> </productRatePlan> <productAttribute> <name>Baiying_attr_00</name> <displayName> <jBos_Common_1_0:key>Label</jBos_Common_1_0:key> </displayName> <type entityName="bmiasia.app.siulib.siu.common.StringSIU"/> <description> <jBos_Common_1_0:key>Label</jBos_Common_1_0:key> </description> <required>false</required> <source>INTERNAL</source> </productAttribute> </BasicProductTemplateType>';
  v_xmltype xmltype;
begin
  v_xmltype := xmltype.createxml(v_xml);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_xmltype.EXTRACT('//productAttribute/name/text()', 'xmlns="http://www.asia.com/app/Product_2_0"').getStringVal());
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes, its working now.... If there are multiple nodes of product attribute then can i get the input in cursor and parse the data and more over we have multiple nodes in product attribute node and i want to bring data sample code is `<productAttribute>
        <name>Baiying_attr_03</name>
        <configParameter name="defaultValue" value="true"/> 
        <required>false</required>
    </productAttribute>
    <productAttribute>
        <name>Baiying_attr_04</name>
        <configParameter name="defaultValue" value="true"/> 
        <required>false</required>
    </productAttribute>`